# Dart test complex async

Tags: dart, dart-async, dart-test

I'm struggling with testing the piece of functionality that is highly asynchronous
. Overal idea is following:

- function A puts data to local storage
- function B monitors local storage and syncs changes to remote storage

So I need to test the function A and ensure that data not only put to local storage but also synced to remote one. My test looks like that:

```dart
    test("Sending data", () async {
      final comm = await Client.create("client1");
      final result = await comm.sendData('client2');
      expect(result, isTrue);
      SyncService.sync(onDone: () async {
        final rComm = await Client.create('client2');
        final keys = await rComm.getData();
        expect(keys.length, 1); // <------ never does that
      });
    });
```

The problem is that test execution doesn't wait for `onDone` callback to be called.
The `SyncService.sync()` function is synchronous and just puts a sync request to the queue. The queue processing function is async. So if I understand Dart execution flow correctly it's put to the end of microtasks queue. My task then would be to put checking of the synchronisation result to the end of microtasks queue after `SyncService.sync()` is called. But in any case the test would finish first and microtasks that are scheduled afterwards wouldn't be tested anyway.

So how to handle that?

Comment: Can you give a link to the `SyncService` class definition? 
If you want to wait until the microtask queue has completed, you can add an `await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);`. This waits for a time-event, which happens no sooner than after the current microtask queue has been emptied.

Comment: I believe that's the one: https://github.com/atsign-foundation/at_client_sdk/blob/e633c21fe57a2aa2c9c03414957ed0c3bc13809d/at_client/lib/src/service/sync_service_impl.dart#L102

If the current microtask queue is emptied it would mean the `test` function is finished too, right?

Comment: The test function is `async`, so the test framework will wait for its returned `Future` to complete. If you add an `await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);`/`await Future((){});` at the end of the `test` callback function, the returned future won't complete until that `await` has completed.
That said, the `SyncService.sync` call does not look like it guarantees being done in the current microtask. You may just have to wait for it to actually complete. Look into [`expectAsync0`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-test_api_expect/expectAsync0.html) and wrap the `onValue` callback with that.